# Use Map with multiple arguments over a nested list

Tags: functions, functional-style, map, pure-function

I noticed there are a few similar questions to mine on here, but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this mapping.

I have sets of data I want to plot, which represent intensity and frames, and I need to convert all of the x data into time, using the frame rate.  To do this I have defined 2 functions

```
frame2Time[frame_, framerate_] := frame/framerate;
transform2Time[lst_, framerate_] := lst /. {x_, y_} :> {frame2Time[x, framerate], y}
```

Then I have three trials for each experiment. `set1` is trial 1 etc....
It is possible that there are not the same number of trials for each experiment.  This is simulated by set2 only have two {x,y} pairs.

```
set1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
set2 = {{1, 11}, {2, 22}}
set3 = {{1, 111}, {2, 222}, {3, 333}}
```

here each lst is each experiment I conducted.

```
lst1 = {set1, set2, set3}
lst2 = 10*lst1
lst3 = 100*lst1
```

Now I want to apply the `transform2Time` to each each trial of each experiment

```
ulttst = Map[transform2Time[# , 10] , {2}]  & /@ {lst1, lst2, lst3} // N
```

However this mapping does not work.  I get an a weird `[2]` embedded in my list that I cannot get rid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current syntax is trying to `Map` the function `{2}` onto each element in the list generated

```
transform2Time[#,10] &/@ {lst2,lst2,lst3}
```

I think this is what you want?

```
ulttst = N@Map[transform2Time[#, 10] &, {lst1, lst2, lst3}, {3}]
```

Comment: Correct, elegant and terse. What more could one ask for?